# How to pass a number of "x" arguments to a function that subset a data.frame and obtain "x" data.frames?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, mapply

I have a question related to applying different arguments in one function in order to obtain different datasets.

I have created a function that takes my data and filter it, according to the value of the arguments in the function (I haven't write the full function becasue I thought it complicates more the explanation of my question).

The function looks something like this:

```
myfun (type, spp, incl){

    #something that subset the data according to
    # type, spp, incl values, and gives as output 
    # a data frame called datanalyisis

    datanalysis
}
```

If we consider that the potential values for my function arguments are:

```
type <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
spp <- c( "Spruce", "Pine","Birch")
incl <- c("no", "yes")
varoptions <- list(type, spp , incl)
varoptions.grid <- expand.grid(varoptions)
```

I get 24 potential combination for all the arguments values.
My goal is to use all the combination of argument values, that I obtained in "varoptions.grid",  in my function. And the result should be 24 different datasets.

I have tried this:

```
var1 <- as.vector(as.character(varoptions$Var1))
var2 <- as.vector(as.character(varoptions$Var2))
var3 <- as.vector(as.character(varoptions$Var3))

finaldata <- mapply ("myfun", type =.var1, spp = .var2, incl=.var3))
```

I think I am obtaining a huge array with all the processes.
I believe I am missing some understanding in how mapply works or I am using the incorrect process to solve my problem.

If you have some input in how to solve this I will much apreciate!, this is my 3th day stuck in this problem :(

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I guess your only problem is the `SIMPLIFY` argument in `mapply`. Try: `mapply ("myfun", type =.var1, spp = .var2, incl=.var3,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`

Comment: Great! thanks nicola, I think that works. If I understood right, now I am getting a list of  24 data.frames. And I can access them by finaldata[ i ]. By doing this I get same results as in the second option that @ColonelBeauvel suggested.